# Property of Euclidean algorithm

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

The Euclid's algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor of two polynomials $r_i(z)$ and $r_0(z)$ can be done iteratively as follows, where we assume $\deg r_ 1 > \deg r_0$.
$$r_{-1}(z)=q_1(z)r_0(z)+r_1(z),\deg r_{-1}=\deg q_1+\deg r_0,\deg r_0>\deg r_1,$$
$$r_{0}(z)=q_2(z)r_1(z)+r_2(z),\deg r_{0}=\deg q_2+\deg r_1,\deg r_1 > \deg r_2,$$
$$r_{1}(z)=q_3(z)r_2(z)+r_3(z),\deg r_{1}=\deg q_3+\deg r_2,\deg r_2 > \deg r_3,$$
$$\vdots$$

This iteration can be rewritten in the matrix form as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
q_i(z) & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
r_{i-1}(z) \\ 
r_{i}(z)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
r_{i-2}(z) \\ 
r_{i-1}(z)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We define $U_i(z),V_i(z)$ as 
$\begin{pmatrix}
U_i(z) & U_{i-1}(z) \\ 
V_i(z) & V_{i-1}(z) 
\end{pmatrix}=
\prod_{k=1}^{i}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_k(z) & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$

According to equation $11$ of [this article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/273276/1-s2.0-S0019995800X01933/1-s2.0-S001999587590090X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEL7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIDvb%2F2MFKaBn0%2Fa%2Fg7pCCibMhDsxep08aNfDn1Gth7NrAiBqdWTt%2B%2BaWHqvdZMx1oNN%2FhqBitrV9ya553yeg4uYd1Cq0AwhmEAIaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMv1NnPsT7XoOFsU9gKpEDgqs7I0Qsg5SH3d2uEpud17bMzTX2WcbFwojfl2GTk3uIZ6on0ajWzHxLHE9YJa%2FA%2FkZdpV0%2BEAu5DuqJ5ov1wQH%2F1WXnc9xam5QjBtw6Rv%2BuHi3V3pmwuond9B4%2BroggOqciHQGtuS4TL0j3f5DtyU8mulrdjiYoiBN7rlxVOU%2F0GaSDsnvzjAey8oD%2F62es50EhPiOvqMSNJswRMyZMVBQItoGD6IDN8tM97K8Iersb%2B5ZQVJ2VjxsLzRDuH%2BeQSW7MIyYbQmu7DLm7g0zCkR3p14eJ2sXmDjZNmEQDpIg6HaY4870hMsVD5XKpJ1Z%2FJM83maEoe414mepJ9T83CPRJLfIbkdyon69yhq1XZoh8ksZ32AH93FLaqtRbZdjaEPBTyHigOE12z5eoPzk50Q2yTBi73Dtoe%2BF8vvgznI7vYVOi4oryE6S8oN9WNCA8yPs7Bfx0ftla8K%2BXuvqBup%2F0rtsFIR2CaUNX9TpXl6UFUwjwrdfMC5m66o0fuG2ZQRS2q9FzzEMB6luTBz7bFyQwvJji8QU67AHqFbNOKJ1WAuYDZhDONN6o2gvxxwW%2BBSZZqE%2BTO0DXFSr7u%2FW0GPKdNsSfUa2iwtUEXw2IhFfpLuVNK87%2Fl8UMXi6Q2xaAVDcIb8HoPnBitebUHz6UH%2B1Y1Pfo2QV8Hl9%2BVhGPl0y8S9jlOvR%2FkMmTd5I8zy17mAOHJWcl%2BCU07sRJi0hy4bXvL7rY8OOc1RrV%2BWYpfvVv3H4VzMtNJXS8G1gj%2BWYWrTry0h0tU5rJ8%2Bi%2BeS7KjXqChTBlMfUPVsaRxG91QgZNYiNl3%2FXD16c5Bzz5xoHTsKX3QWQfyygCUQfQ6KvvkjQsPZ1JSw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200203T223212Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYTFWVGEVI%2F20200203%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=bda8d591b0cc14ba0e09b0f873c100483a032681bb74bba68351524b8a7434f4&hash=d140dec5dccb55d50bef4ee8989d94295c021963445380ae1824b6159b328e27&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S001999587590090X&tid=spdf-4234d6a2-8ec3-4811-b443-b6fd54fa1f02&sid=3df2ae785d3a944f967ad588c31aa5a3be81gxrqa&type=client) on page 91, 
$$\deg U_i = \deg r_{-1} - \deg r_{i-1}$$
 will be satisfied. Is this obvious?

Author say this is equivalent to $\deg r_{i-1}=\deg r_{-1} - \sum_{j=1}^i \deg q_{i}$.

How to prove this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily prove both claims by induction.

For $i=1$, we have $U_1=q_1$ and $\deg q_1=\deg r_{-1}-\deg r_0$. 
[Though, we could as well have started with $i=0$, when $U_0=1$.]

Can you continue with the generic case?

Comment: I got it. From $\deg r_{-1}=\deg q_1+\deg r_0,  \deg r_{0}=\deg q_2+\deg r_1, \deg r_{1}=\deg q_3+\deg r_2, \ldots $, we get $\deg r_{-1}=\deg q_1+\deg r_0=\deg q_1+\deg q_2+\deg r_1=\deg q_1+\deg q_2+\deg q_3+\deg r_2=\ldots$. Thank you.